# removing svg transparent bakcground

Tags: svg, jvectormap

I use jvectormap. I create map. I need to save this svg map as image. I use a plugin named saveSvgAsPng.js. It works ok. My problem is that ,png image makes transparent. Is there a method that I remove svg background transparency?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the usage Docs for `saveSvgAsPng` ?

https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng

```
saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("diagram"), "diagram.png", {backgroundColor: "white"});
```

Try and pass `"white"` or the HEX color value `"#FFFFFF"`

Pass `backgroundColor` in the options object:

Available Options:

- **backgroundColor** — Creates a PNG with the given background color. Defaults to transparent.
- **scale** — Changes the resolution of the output PNG. Defaults to 1, the same dimensions as the source SVG.
- **selectorRemap** — A function that takes a CSS selector and produces its replacement in the CSS that's inlined into the SVG. Useful if your SVG style selectors are scoped by ancestor elements in your HTML document.

Comment: No worries glad to help!